# Isotope add element flexbox grid

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-isotope, flexboxgrid

Almost done with my project, just one thing isn't working properly. I used Isotope for deleting items and this works perfectly. The item gets removed and the next item slides in it's place. Now I want to add items to the grid. If I remove the Isotope functionality it all works, but I want it to work together with Isotope (because of the nice transitions etc). If I use my current code, nothing happens, except for the last item (it gets cloned but isn't added to the grid).

To reproduce problem:
 - Click on Add user
 - Nothing happens

Working:
 - Remove the isotope js file from the header and the isotope js from the JS file (line 7 to 16)
 - Click on Add user
 - User gets added to the grid nicely

Here is a snippet of my JS:

```
  $('.js-add-user').on( 'click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.js-grid-item:last').clone().insertAfter($('.js-grid .js-grid-item:last'));
});
```

See my Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/r3c05odv/3/

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use isotope's append method:

```
$('.js-add-user').on( 'click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $items = $('.js-grid-item:last').clone();
 // append items to grid
 $grid.append( $items )
// add and lay out newly appended items
  .isotope( 'appended', $items );   
 });
```

The only issue is, since you use `$('.js-grid-item:last').clone();`, if you delete all items, there is no "last" to clone.

Comment: Thank you, this works. But you are right about the clone function, do you know another simple way of doing this?